# Linking excel data with pictures to access

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

When I create a new table in access with new data source -> excel command and use 
Link to data (that excel sheet also contains pictures for records. each record has employee photo), access did not import them (photos) to its database instead it shows blank columns.
Use of MS Access is because of easy creation of reports.
How to import data with pictures to access?

The picture used is in jpg format.
I also tried using bitmap images with same results.
I have tried on ms office 2007 and 2016 with same results.

Is there any possible solution exist?

Comment: Access use a Field Type  called Object Linking and Embedding (OLE) to store images and documents. By default, OLE created a bitmap equivalent of the image or document. I guess your Access database don't have that type of field !

Comment: I have that type of field in access. I can manually create the same table by right clicking and then insert object.

Comment: You could also store the pictures somewhere externally (i.e. not in Access), and then store the path to the image as a text field in Access.

Comment: How could it be used to generate reports with employee photos?